# Solving a partial derivative explicitly without initial conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given a function,

$$u_{xy}=x^2y ,u(x,y) $$

I was wondering if there was a better way to solve this problem aside from using basic calculus, particularly using differential equations

Obviously I can do 
$$F(x)F(y) + c(y) + c(x)$$
by integrating but could I use a separation of variables for $u_{xy}$ or some other method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that $f(x)+g(y)$ is the solution of $u_{xy}=0$.

For the term $x^2y$ on the right hand side; we have

$\frac{1}{DD'}x^2y=\frac{1}{D}x^2(y^2/2)=(x^3/3)(y^2/2)=x^3y^2/6$.

Thus the solution of given pde is $u(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)+\frac{x^3y^2}{6}$

Comment: yes, this is the solution I am aware of, I was wondering if there was a change of variables or such that I could use to solve it aswell

Comment: @yipz..Use separation of variables by letting $u=X(x).Y(y)$ to reduce it into ODE's.

Comment: then I can solve those two ODE's implicitly? S.T. I have $x' -cx^2=0$ and $y' - cy=0$ for example?

Comment: @yipz..$\frac{X'X}{x^2}=\frac{y}{Y'Y}=k$ (say) gives you $\frac{X^2}{2}=\frac{kx^3}{3}+a$ and $\frac{kY^2}{2}=\frac{y^2}{2}+b$. Then $u=X.Y$ is solution